# Laravel query builder return multiple column values in where array clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

In my Laravel project a user can find data from a table via a front-end GUI that allows them to pick and choose tables and columns (with restrictions). I'm trying to search by multiple different values in a where clause on a column called `event_action` so that I can bring back multiple results, I appear to be getting some kind of results back, but I'm not seeing all of my results?

```php
$results = DB::table('my_table')
             ->select('event_category', 'event_action', 'event_count', 'created_at')
             ->where([
               ['event_category', 'my category'],
               ['event_action', ['value1', 'value2']],
               ['created_at', '>=', '2021-03-01']
             ])
             ->get();
```

My `event_action` column has many rows where the value of some rows have `value1` and others have `value2`, but in my returned results I'm only seeing one or the other, not both, for instance, in Tinker:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3501
 all: [
   {#3433
     +"event_category": "my category",
     +"event_action": "value2",
     +"event_count": "16",
     +"created_at": "2021-03-01 01:00:03",
   },
   {#3499
     +"event_category": "my category",
     +"event_action": "value2",
     +"event_count": "16",
     +"created_at": "2021-03-01 01:15:06",
   },
   {#3464
     +"event_category": "my category",
     +"event_action": "value2",
     +"event_count": "19",
     +"created_at": "2021-03-01 01:30:05",
   },
   {#3465
     +"event_category": "my category",
     +"event_action": "value2",
     +"event_count": "21",
     +"created_at": "2021-03-01 01:45:07",
   },
   {#3466
     +"event_category": "my category",
     +"event_action": "value2",
     +"event_count": "24",
     +"created_at": "2021-03-01 02:00:05",
   },
 ],
}
```

Comment: what do you mean?
is like i search "r" and it retruns anything in that col that has an r in it ?

Comment: Well, I should be seeing results that contain `value2` and `value1`, because I have rows in my database where the column values on some contain `value2` and others contain `value1`, why would I only ever be getting back `value2`?

Comment: maybe try orWhere, if the user can search multiple values add a loop

Answer (score 0):

For Date, use whereDate and for multiple values in single field, you can use whereIn

```
$results = DB::table('my_table')
             ->select('event_category', 'event_action', 'event_count', 'created_at')
             ->where('event_category', '=','my category')
             ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date('2021-03-01'))
             ->whereIn('event_action', ['value1', 'value2'])
             ->get();
```